# Saxon Xpath namespace

Tags: xpath, saxon

Given the following xml:

```
<Document xmlns="urn:company.com:catalog.01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <book>
        <author>Wells</author>
    </book>
</Document>
```

With Xerces the following xpath query works:

```
//urn:company.com:catalog.01:author
```

When I use Saxon (v 8.7) I a StaticError with message 'Invalid QName local part {company.com:catalog....}'.

What should the Xpath query look like to get the value of author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xerces should not allow an XPath expression like

```
//urn:company.com:catalog.01:author
```

XPath is XML Names compliant, so a `:` (colon) in a QName divides the prefix part from local name part of a QName.

There is no syntax in XPath to use the full expanded QName in name test:

You could use

```
//*[local-name()='author'][namespace-uri()='urn:company.com:catalog.01']
```

Comment: @drifwood: Yes, in fact any string is valid as namespace URI, besides it should be valid URI.

Comment: @Alejandro: I performed some editorial edits. Also, the requirement for a namespace to be a valid URI is not strictly enforced -- language processor do not raise an error if a namespace isn't a valid URI. Therefore, this isn't a requirement -- just a recommendation.

Comment: How would one optimize this query? In the current state it will search through all elements for a match. If for instance there was another author element in a child element of book, how can I change this query to only return /book/author?

Comment: I read the above xpath as find all elements with name author and default namespace urn:company.com:catalog.01. I would assume it would pickup all elements at all levels that match but doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: @driftwood: You are right. Your expression will become `//*[local-name()='book'][namespace-uri()='urn:company.com:catalog.01']/*[local-name()='author'][namespace-uri()='urn:company.com:catalog.01']`. That's why you should better register a namespace.

Comment: Update: in XPath 3.0 there is now a syntax to use a full expanded name, it is written `//Q{urn:company.com:catalog.01}author`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your XSL file. I went through this recently, and the solution was to make sure the xsl file has a line like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:c="urn:company.com:catalog.01">
```

Then your references to elements in the xml file are prefixed with "c:":

```
//c:author
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not used in an XSL file. I am using the XPath API for quick configurable classification of messages etc. But thanks for the info it will be useful in future.