# Possible to process XHTML with Saxon?

Tags: xpath, xhtml, saxon

I can use `xmllint` and process HTML/XHTML input with XPath 1.0. For example:

`xmllint --xpath "//title" --html http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/ 2>/dev/null`

outputs expected, but with Saxon:

`java -cp /usr/share/java/saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -s:"http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/" -qs:"//title"`

no results.
If run against HTTP document connection is reset after 2 min, and on local document it exits w/o result after couple o minutes processing

In Saxon [documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xquery/commandline.xml) I can't find anything related to processing XHTML documents

---

I found this question: [Saxon Xpath namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399552/saxon-xpath-namespace) and I'm updating question with more information:

Here is `xmllint` example without using html parser (no `--html` switch):

`xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='title'][namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']" http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/`

which outputs:

```
<title>XSL Transformations (XSLT) Version 2.0</title>
```

Again using Saxon:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -s:"http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/" -qs:"//*[local-name()='title'][namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']"
```

No results

Comment: Sure, it can, as long as it's well-formed XML (i.e. it's actually valid XHTML). One note, XHTML elements are in a namespace (`http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`). Be sure you're specifying the namespace.

Comment: `http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/` *is* XHTML source document. It passes HTML tidy XML test and it's generated with it, as it can easily be checked

Comment: I think you missed what I pasted. It's not the same string: `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. You'll never match anything with `//title` because it does not account for the namespace.

Comment: What is not same string? Namespace is defined in source document: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`. How would you suggest I change XPath pattern?

Comment: First, the expression `//title` selects all `title` elements that are in *no namespace*. Second, shouldn't you be providing a stylesheet to Saxon (i.e. not simply an XPath expression)?

Comment: Can you provide example of how to use namespace in XPath expression as you seem to suggest that? XSL should be provided to Saxon XSLT processor, in above example it's XQuery (`net.sf.saxon.Query`)

Comment: I get an I/O error when using the URL in the `-s` (the connection resets), but it works fine if I save the source to a local file. It does take a while though. Also, I used this query string: `-qs:"//*:title"` This returns the same title as xmllint (`*:title` is title in any namespace).

Comment: Thanks. That expression indeed works. Also simplifies things alot, as you can imagine how above pattern (with assigned namespace) would look for some more common query. And it's incredibly slooow - it takes around 1 min to process example document, while xmllint takes less then 1 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XHTML document is an XML document, so you can process it in the same way as any other XML document. Note that if it's XHTML, then most of the elements are likely to be in a namespace, and you need to take this into account. Setting the XHTML namespace as the default namespace might be useful (though sadly in XQuery this also makes it the default namespace for the output - XSLT does this better).

It's common for XHTML documents to contain a reference to the XHTML DTD on the W3C server, and over the last year W3C have stopped responding to requests to retrieve this resource because they can't handle the load. This means that you may experience long delays and I/O errors. In response to this, Saxon 9.4 includes a local copy of the XHTML DTD and satisfies requests from its local copy. With earlier releases you can achieve the same effect using OASIS catalogs.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Michael. I'll try to decrypt meaning of local XHTML DTD copy ;) I'm curious if you can comment why it takes so unnaturally long for Saxon to process query (like in DevNull commented query) on local XHTML copy of http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20 for example. I don't have much experience, but otherwise Saxon doesn't seem slow, from what I tried so far

Comment: As I mentioned, if there's an inordinate delay it's because the XML parser is asking W3C to serve the DTD, and W3C isn't serving it. Saxon is sitting there waiting, just like you are...

Comment: presumably `xmllint` now caches a copy?

Comment: No, but Saxon does.